# how to publishing local .m2 repository all artifacts to jfrog repository

Tags: java, maven, maven-2, pom.xml, artifactory

I upgraded JFrog Artifactory to the latest version, and after upgrade I see some artifacts are missing, and also pom files, I still have them in local .m2 directory. Is there a way I can republish/deploy  all these artifacts to a remote Artifactory repository at once ?

Answer (score 2):

Use mvn deploy to republish/deploy your artifacts into remote repository.

Ensure that you are pointing the deploy directory to the remote repository in your master pom.

If you want to specifically upload a file, use the following command

```
mvn deploy:deploy-file -DpomFile=your pom -Dfile=the jar you want to upload
 -Durl=Url of the repository where the artifact need to be uploaded 
 -DrepositoryId=repository ID
```

References:

https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/usage.html

https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-remote.html

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/examples/deploy-ssh-external.html

https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/core/MAVEN/config_maven.htm#MAVEN314

Answer (score 2):

Based on your comment that those artifacts are missing from a [remote repository](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Remote+Repositories), there are 2 possible options:

1. [Importing](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Importing+and+Exporting#ImportingandExporting-Import) the repository content from the local .m2 directory. Artifactory support the option of importing content from a directory on the server or an archive. It is possible to import files into remote repository caches.
2. Re-downloading the artifacts from the remote repository in order to repopulate the cache. This can be done by running a build which has those artifacts as dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

- Package your directory into an archive (tar) file.
- click "Deploy" and select your archive
- checkboxes will appear : check "Deploy as Bundle Artifact"
- fix the "target path" to your need
- validate and you're done